# Magento 2 - Category page `addAttributeToSort` not working on custom product attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, sorting, category-page

I used the following code for `sorting` on `category page`.

```
if($this->getCurrentOrder() =="latest_products")
    {
       $collection->addAttributeToSort('significance', 'DESC')->getSelect()->order("e.entity_id desc");
    }
```

In order to debug, I use following on my `local instance` but surprisingly there is no `ORDER BY significance DESC` in query as well

```
$collection->getSelect(); die;
```

This is my configuration settings

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar kind of problem because I was working on category page product sorting. As I understand, you made custom product attribute `significance` for sorting. So please make you have set `Used in Product Listing` to `Yes` in your custom product attribute. It is one of the possible cause.

[image]

As I look your configuration setting, the reason is because you set the `Use Flat Catalog Product` to `Yes`. So you have to set `Used in Product Listing` to `Yes`.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: What a shame! I don't have any idea it is as much easy. THanKs mate you are the savior.